# How to use second overload of std::optional<T>::emplace

Tags: c++, stdoptional

In the `std::optional::emplace` [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/emplace) there is an overload that accepts `std::initializer_list`:

```
template< class U, class... Args >
T& emplace( std::initializer_list<U> ilist, Args&&... args );
```

provided that

> std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list&, Args&&...>::value is true

I thought that it might be used to emplace POD types, but apparently this is not how it works (in other SO topics it was explained that `emplace` functions are using `()` syntax instead of `{}`):

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
int main()
{
    A normalA{1, 2, 3};  // this is OK
    std::cout << std::is_constructible<A, std::initializer_list<int>&, int, int, int>::value << std::endl;  // false
    std::cout << std::is_constructible<A, std::initializer_list<int>&>::value << std::endl;  // false
    std::optional<A> optA;
    // optA.emplace({1, 2, 3});  // this is NOK
    optA.emplace(A{1, 2, 3});  // I can walk it around with copy-ctor
}
```

I can write the constructor accepting `initializer_list`:

```
struct B
{
    B(std::initializer_list<int> l) {/* some impl here */}
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

and then call `emplace` like this:

```
    std::optional<B> optB;
    optB.emplace({1, 2, 3});
```

but shouldn't first `emplace` overload `T& emplace( Args&&... args );` be enough for that?
I thought that it might be useful for the array types, but `std::optional<int[]> xxx;` does not compile anyway.

Can you please provide some example where second `std::optional::emplace` overload is used.

Comment: Probably to make `emplace({1,2,3}, allocator);` work for `optional<vector<int>>`. Even without the allocator argument the overload is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but shouldn't first emplace overload T& emplace( Args&&... args ); be enough for that?

It isn't because a *braced-init-list*, i.e. `{1, 2, 3}` has no type.  Because it has no type, there is nothing to compiler can do to deduce what `Args` should be.  We need to have an overload that explicitly takes a `std::initializer_list` so that we can avoid the compiler not being able to deduce what the *braced-init-list* should be considered as.